# tasklist.exe, Win Server 2008 R2, file name has spaces

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a client running Apple's *FileMaker Pro Advanced* on *Windows Server 2008 R2*. The associated executable is "FileMaker Pro Advanced.exe" (note the spaces). My client has had problem with "something" shutting down FileMaker; part of one solution is to write a batch file to run every 15 minutes that'll start FileMaker if it's not running. I'm helping with the batch file.

I proposed code based on this:

```
set target=FileMaker Pro Advance.exe
set startWith=(batch file that starts FileMaker)
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq '%target%’" /NH 2>NUL | find /I "%target%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" %startWith%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto :EOF
```

Please note: The design of the **tasklist** command line required use of a set of quotes; I used double quotes for those. The presence of spaces in the file name would seem to require another set of quotes; I used single quotes above.

My technique doesn't work; I get an error message about a poorly formed command. Sigh.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Absent better suggestion, I'll ask the sys admin to let me rename that file to something like "FileMakerProAdvanced.exe"; that should work. I'll only get that permission a percentage of the time I ask. I'll need something else in case they decline my request.

(The hawk-eyed among you will notice that the filename is 26 characters long. It seems **tasklist** has a 25 character limit. I can get around that (in the **find** command, for example) by searching for "FileMaker Pro Advanced.ex"; that's all **tasklist** provides **find**. And I can use double quotes in the **find** command.)

Thanks in advance for solutions and commiserating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any problem with spaces in the imagename filter so there is no need for a workaround, just remove the inner single quotes

```
set "target=FileMaker Pro Advance.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq %target%"
```

And the problem with the output length is just for the column mode. You can change to csv output format

```
tasklist /fi "imagenane eq %target%" /nh /fo:csv | find /i "%target%" >nul
```

Or, as you are not retrieving any data from the output, instead of hidding the headers, as them are only present if a matching process has been found, check for the presence of the headers

```
tasklist /fi "imagenane eq %target%" | find "========" >nul
```

Comment: A stellar response. Timely (an hour!) Well worded. Gave us new things to think about. Your advice is working. Thank you. Many times over. We deeply appreciate the time you took to respond. [edit for spelling]